# When i restore a VM in Azure , does it restore the disks as well?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM in Azure, I want to restore so I am using the Operations->Backup and selecting restore VM
I am given the following

[image]

If I restore this VM from one of the restore points and select create new VM , will it create data disks and I can simply connect to the new one using RDP or do i need to copy across data disks from the old ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#restore-options)  if you choose create new VM it means it will create everything VM and storage.

> If a VM restore fails because an Azure VM SKU wasn't available in the specified region of Azure, or because of any other issues, Azure Backup still restores the disks in the specified resource group.

The other option you can restore just disk and then you can create new VM manually and just attach disk.

Comment: Perfect , I would prefer to create a new VM and verify then delete the old